# Android connecting to IPv6 address fails on some devices

Tags: android, sockets, ipv6, samsung-galaxy

The code tries to connect using both IPv4 and IPv6.

On some devices connecting to IPv6 fails, while other devices on the same Wifi-Router have no problem.

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress [] adrall = InetAddress.getAllByName("www.google.com");
            for(InetAddress adr : adrall)
            {
                try {
                    Log.d("TEST", "Connecting to " + adr.getHostAddress());
                    new Socket().connect(new InetSocketAddress(adr, 80), 2000);
                    Log.d("TEST", "Success!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("TEST", "Fail!");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
});
```

For example the output using a Samsung Galaxy S9 is:

```
Connecting to 2a00:1450:4001:808::2004
Fail!
Connecting to 172.217.16.132
Success!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the failing devices even have an IPv6 address on their external interface (i.e. the WiFi interface, localhost does not matter)? If not then they connect connect to IPv6.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich: Yes, I have just checked it: the Wifi interface does have an IPv6 address on all devices.